# How to remove source files during production deployment of a react application

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to deploy an application build using react and i wanted to know what all security measures i need to take while pushing to production.

I ran `npm run build` command and i got the build folder structure as shown below.

[image: folder structure after running 'npm run build' command]

Then i deployed this build folder to production site and i can see from my browser console that my source files are also present as shown in following screenshot.

[image: console view from production site]

How do i remove these source files from production so that users wont get to see my source code and they will only see the minified files?

What all security measures should be taken before deploying to production?

Comment: You should remove the `.map` files for that

Comment: how do i perform that? And i dont see any .map files above

Comment: those are inside `build/static/js` having extension `.map`

Answer (score 3):

Change this line in your package.json from

```
"build": "react-scripts build",
```

to

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
```

Answer (score 2):

Review your webpack configuration (in your package.json) to
remove or comment out the line:

```
 devtool: 'source-map',
```

More options on https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: I am new to React.  Where exactly is the devtool: 'source-map'?  I've looked through all of the webpack node modules in my React environment and could not find this setting.

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: Good! For everyone, there are several ways to configure Webpack but the most common one is to use webpack.config.js in the root folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the .map files from your build.
to do that you just have to:

1. CREATE A FILE .env in the same folder of your package.json
2. PUT THIS IN THE .env FILE: GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

That is all!
For me works!